# Dynamically parse data for table rows

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5, setstate

I am trying to parse the data dynamically for the table. So far I have tried the following to display the table.

```
  renderTableData = () => {
    return this.props.data.map((item, index) => {
      const { name, value } = item;
      return (
        <tr key={index}>
          <td>{name}</td>
          <td>{value}</td>
        </tr>
      );
    });
  };
```

Here I am hardcoding the field values for displaying. I need this to be dynamic

Full code: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-basic-class-component-3kpp5?file=/src/Table.js:0-805

```
import * as React from "react";

class Table extends React.Component {
  renderTableData = () => {
    return this.props.data.map((item, index) => {
      const { name, value } = item;
      return (
        <tr key={index}>
          <td>{name}</td>
          <td>{value}</td>
        </tr>
      );
    });
  };

  renderTableHeader = () => {
    let header = Object.keys(this.props.data[0]);
    return header.map((key, index) => {
      return <th key={index}>{key.toUpperCase()}</th>;
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>{this.renderTableHeader()}</tr>
            {this.renderTableData()}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Table;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop through object properties with [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)

```
 renderTableData = () => {
    return this.props.data.map((item, index) => {
      return (
        <tr key={index}>
          {Object.entries(item).map(([key, value])=> <td key={key}>{value}</td>)}
        </tr>
      );
    });
  };
```

However, as you can see you lost control of the order of columns. Additionaly there might be columns you don't wish to display.

You can tackle that by appending `Object.entries` with custom implemented functions

```
<tr key={index}>
  {Object.entries(item)
   .filter(predicateFunction)
   .sort(sortingFunction).map(([key, value])=> <td key={key}>{value}</td>)}
</tr>
```

Or switch to [react-data-table](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-data-table-component)

Comment: Tried with your solution, It doesnt work in the sandbox

Comment: Updated answer. I put wrong param in object entries func